# Unit test KeyValueDiffers, angular jest

Tags: angular, jestjs, jasmine

I am having a component that uses `KeyValueDiffers`.

```
constructor(private differs: KeyValueDiffers, private toastr: CustomToastService) { }
```

In the `spec.ts` file I have added `KeyValueDiffers` in the providers array, but when I try to run the unit test, it is giving this error:

```
Can't resolve all parameters for KeyValueDiffers: (?).
```

How to resolve that?

EDIT: in spec.ts file, it is imported like this:

```
providers: [
    KeyValueDiffers
  ]
```

Comment: I think this lack some [mre], but have you correctly imported the service?

Comment: @Vega, added the EDIT to show how it is imported in spec.ts.

Comment: yes, component is working fine, having trouble in unit testing due to  'KeyValueDiffers' as dependency in component constructor. Somehow it is not working in unit testing

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this:

```
const myServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('RealService', ['method1', 'method2', 'method3']);
```

and in providers:

```
providers: [{ provide: RealService, useValue: myServiceMock }];
```

You miss methods for that service...